# Evaluation of as.integer(max(factorize(15)))

Tags: r

This appears quite bizarre to me and I would like an explanation.  I

```
library(gmp)
factorize(15) # => "3" "5"
max(factorize(15)) # => "5"
as.integer("5") # => 5
as.integer(max(factorize(15))) # => 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 5 0 0 0
```

I can do what I want with:

```
max(as.numeric(factorize(15))) # => [1]5
```

But it shook me that I couldn't rely on nesting functions inside of functions in a supposedly scheme-like language.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: > str(max(factorize(15)))
Class 'bigz'  raw [1:16] 01 00 00 00 ...

Comment: 'max(as.integer(factorize(15)))' works. 'factorize(15)' returns a vector of class '"bigz"', so first change the class then take the max I guess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the answer is in the representation of `factorize(15)`:

```
> dput(factorize(15))
structure(c(02, 00, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 03, 
00, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 05, 00, 00, 00), class = "bigz")
```

and

```
> dput(max(factorize(15)))
structure(c(01, 00, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 01, 00, 00, 00, 05, 
00, 00, 00), class = "bigz")
```

...`max` and `as.numeric` (actually, `as.double`) have methods for the `bigz` class, but apparently `as.integer` does not:

```
> methods(max)
[1] max.bigq max.bigz
> methods(as.numeric)
no methods were found
> methods(as.double)
[1] as.double.bigq     as.double.bigz     as.double.difftime as.double.POSIXlt 
> methods(as.integer)
no methods were found
```

...so `as.integer` treats the `bigz` objects as a simple vector of values.

Answer (score 3):

The result of `factorize` in package `gmp` is a object of class `bigz`:

```
> factorize(15)
[1] "3" "5"
> str(factorize(15))
Class 'bigz'  raw [1:28] 02 00 00 00 ...
```

From the help for `?biginteger` it seems the following coercion functions are defined for objects of class `bigz`:

- `as.character`
- `as.double`

Notice there is no `as.integer` in the list.  So, to convert your result to numeric, you *must* use `as.double`:

```
> as.double(max(factorize(15)))
[1] 5
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it seems odd that the 'bigz' class does not have an as.integer method. However, it may be that the whole point of the gmp package is to keep its values "out of the hands" of the less capable regular R representation structures. The authors did not choose (yet) to offer an integer coercion function but you could always suggest to them that they should. As @Andrie demonstrated, such a function can be defined to intercept what would otherwise would be a .Primitive call, which is what you now get with `as.integer()`.

```
require(gmp)
methods(as)
```